# Can I fine-tune BERT using only masked language model and next sentence prediction?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

So if I understand correctly there are mainly two ways to adapt BERT to a specific task: fine-tuning (all weights are changed, even pretrained ones) and feature-based (pretrained weights are frozen). However, I am confused.

1. When to use which one? If you have unlabeled data (unsupervised learning), should you then use fine-tuning?
2. If I want to fine-tuned BERT, isn't the only option to do that using masked language model and next sentence prediction? And also: is it necessary to put another layer of neural network on top?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach should be to try the pre-trained weights. Generally it works well. However if you are working on a different domain (e.g.: Medicine), then you'll need to fine-tune on data from new domain. Again you might be able to find pre-trained models on the domains (e.g.: [BioBERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08746)).

For adding layer, there are slightly different approaches depending on your task. E.g.: For question-answering, have a look at [TANDA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04118) paper (Transfer and Adapt Pre-Trained Transformer Models for Answer Sentence Selection). It is a very nice easily readable paper which explains the transfer and adaptation strategy. Again, hugging-face has modified and pre-trained models for most of the standard tasks.

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing word sense induction for (my) language, where there is only "base" bert model for now. I've seen some implementations of this task for english using masked language modeling, so I'm wandering if masked language model is just of the ways to fine-tune BERT or is it mandatory step?

Comment: Yes MLM is the standard for training if you are starting from scratch. However nothing is mandatory.